# Can we integrate java compiler in an azure application?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, azure, cloud

I want to build an application on windows azure platform that will have minimal compilation powers for the java language.

Is it possible to integrate a java compiler in such an application?
If not, is there an alternate way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scott Golightly has a video on [running Java on Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/ee941631) - so you'd just need to follow similar steps to get the JDK installed, and then run the compiler from your code.

Of course if you can find a Java compiler implemented in .NET, that would be simpler as there's better tooling for .NET deployment. One option may be to run [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) which implements the Java environment within .NET.